# NSDictionary: Find a specific object and remove it

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have `NSMutableDictionary` that looks like this:

```
category =     (
            {
        description =             (
                            {
                id = 1;
                name = Apple;
            },
                            {
                id = 5;
                name = Pear;
            },
                            {
                id = 12;
                name = Orange;
            }
        );
        id = 2;
        name = Fruits;
    },
            {
        description =             (
                            {
                id = 4;
                name = Milk;
            },
                            {
                id = 7;
                name = Tea;
            }
        );
        id = 5;
        name = Drinks;
    }
);
```

Now, when a user performs an action in my application, I get the @"name"-value of the object, like "Apple". I would like to remove that object from the dictionary, but how will can I reach this object with the

```
[myDictionary removeObjectForKey:]
```

method?

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to do is remove an object from the `description` array and the object you want to delete is the one with the given name. Correct?

Comment: Hi rmaddy, this is correct!

Comment: Peel the onion.  One layer at a time.

Answer (score 2):

At a high level you need to get a reference to the "description" array. Then iterate through the array getting each dictionary. Check the dictionary to see if it has the matching "name" value. If so, remove that dictionary from the "description" array.

```
NSString *name = ... // the name to find and remove
NSMutableArray *description = ... // the description array to search
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < description.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *data = description[i];
    if ([data[@"name"] isEqualToString:name]) {
        [description removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, he has two description arrays inside two separate dictionaries inside an array which is inside the "category" element of a dictionary he's not showing us.

Comment: @HotLicks I figure if he was able to get to the "Apple" object to begin with, he should know how to get a reference to the proper "dictionary" array. :)

Comment: Thank you, but I can´t seem to get the description array right. About the "Apple" value, I get that directly, don´t need to go through an dictionary. @HotLicks I think I shown the complete dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

To remove something from an INNER array:

```
NSString* someFood = <search argument>;
NSArray* categories = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"category"];
for (NSDictionary* category in categories) {
    NSArray* descriptions = [category objectForKey:@"description"];
    for (int i = descriptions.count-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        NSDictionary* description = [descriptions objectForIndex:i];
        if ([[description objectForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:someFood]) {
            [descriptions removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }
    }
}
```

To remove an entire group (eg, "Fruits") from the outer array is simpler.

Comment: FYI - You can't call `removeObjectAtIndex:` on an `NSArray`.

Comment: @rmaddy -- Ah, true.  The array must be copied to a mutable first (if it isn't already).  Missed that point.  (Generally the array will NOT be mutable if received from JSON parsing.  And, to replace that array the *containing* object must be mutable, all the way back to the root.)

Comment: Thank you, this seem to work, but (sorry for being such a pain in the ass), this does not remove the object from the original NSDictionary, which is the key part.

Comment: @marsrover - That's what I was talking about.  If the whole tree is from JSON (or otherwise not mutable) you pretty much have to convert it all to mutable first.  Simple to do, but a PITA.