# Remove values from dictionary in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I have a JSON object as such:

```
The Result {
    shops = ({
        date = "2015-07-22T14:14:48.867618";
        "num_items" = 0;
        score = "-1";
        "total_spend" = 0;
    },
    {
        date = "2015-07-22T14:17:03.713194";
        "num_items" = 1;
        score = 5;
        "total_spend" = "1.85";
    });
}
```

And My Code:

```
let dict = result as! NSDictionary
var mutDict: NSMutableDictionary = dict.mutableCopy() as!     NSMutableDictionary

for (key, value) in mutDict {
    for i in 0..<backendArray.count {
        if value[i].objectForKey("num_items") === 0
            {
                //delete that shop only
            }
     }       
}
```

I want to delete the whole first shop and all of it's contents, but not the second shop or the shops.

I don't want to turn it into an Array, because I can't figure out how to turn it back. Data needs to be stored still as a Dictionary. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004770/nsdictionary-find-a-specifik-object-and-remove-it

Comment: I know how to remove objects from Arrays I want to remove it from the Dictionary!

Comment: then create another dictionary with necessary objects :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791506/remove-keys-values-from-nsdictionary

Comment: No, you don't want to remove it from the dictionary, you want to remove it from the array that is inside your dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

The key in the dictionary is `shops`, and it has an array as value. So you are not actually deleting the shops with `num_items == 0` from the *dictionary* but from the array (which is probably not mutable). So create a new array by filtering the old one, and update the value for `shops` in dictionary, e.g.:

```
dict["shops"] = (dict["shops"] as NSArray?)?.filter { (shop: Dictionary) in
    (shop["num_items"] as NSNumber?)?.integerValue > 0
}
```

(Verify type checks and casts as necessary; the code you gave is not stand-alone so can't test directly in a playground.)

Comment: I read the OP's post differently. I thing she's saying that she wants to delete any (outer) dictionary entry that contains at least one zero entry in its array. We need the OP to clarify.

Comment: Doesn't work :( I want to delete the whole shop it says something about AnyObject not having method filter

Comment: @HannahLouisaCarney Well, that's the problem with not posting testable code… Try the edited version which adds the `as NSArray`. If that doesn't work, try changing `NSArray` to `Array`. If that doesn't work, post _details_ as to how it doesn't work, i.e., copypaste the exact error message, not “it says something about”.

Answer (score 2):

So use the `NSMutableDictionary` method `removeObjectForKey`. You will need to break out of your inner for loop when you delete an entry however.

```
let dict = result as! NSDictionary
var mutDict: NSMutableDictionary = dict.mutableCopy() as!     NSMutableDictionary

dictLoop: for (key, value) in mutDict {
    for i in 0..<backendArray.count {
        if value[i].objectForKey("num_items") === 0
            {
              //delete that shop only
              mutDict.removeObjectForKey(key)
              continue dictLoop
            }
     }       
}
```

Comment: What does "Doesn't work" mean, specifically? Doesn't compile? Compiles but doesn't give the desired result? Crashes? Give details.